# iphone - UIView Move objects in the screen?

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder

I have a CustomView (Expand View) in my main view, which is suppose to expand.
I have a bunch of other objects at the bottom of my ExpandView.
I want to move all these objects down as my ExpandView expands.

Is it possible to do this in interface builder, and relate these objects to my ScrollView so that they would move automatically as my ExpandView grows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You will have to do this in code.